# Synchronization between different threads/processes in Java or Android?

Tags: java, android

My application has an activity, an service, and several event receivers.

They seems to be controlled by different processes or threads, so I have to figure out a way to synchronize my global variables.

The method I use is the shared preference in android which provide a way to store/read the information in a simple database.

However, I found there might be synchronization issues due to the different processes/threads may happen to read/write the shared preference at the same time.

It might cause the following ANR (application not responding) issue when I receive some events.

```
DALVIK THREADS:
"main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x4001d8b0 self=0xcd30
  | sysTid=4899 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=-1345017808
  | schedstat=( 1374573162 1397685629 3862 )
  at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.openImpl(Native Method)
  at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(OSFileSystem.java:152)
  at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:97)
  at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:69)
  at android.app.ContextImpl$SharedPreferencesImpl.createFileOutputStream(ContextImpl.java:3034)
  at android.app.ContextImpl$SharedPreferencesImpl.writeFileLocked(ContextImpl.java:3094)
  at android.app.ContextImpl$SharedPreferencesImpl.access$300(ContextImpl.java:2824)
  at android.app.ContextImpl$SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl.commit(ContextImpl.java:3009)
  at com.test.myapp.myapp.c((null):-1)
  at com.test.myapp.myapp.a((null):-1)
  at com.test.myapp.EventNetwork.onReceive((null):-1)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2810)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3200(ActivityThread.java:125)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2083)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I'm not sure my activity, service, or receivers are controlled by the different processes ,or just different threads in the same process.

So, I think that I may need a global mutex to avoid those processes/threads from reading/writing the shared preference at the same time.

Thanks for any responses or suggestions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I will suggest to put your `SharedPreference` code in a method and use `synchronized`

```
synchronized private void foo()
{
      //Do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Does it also work with different processes ? Because I'm not sure if my activity, service and receivers will in the same process.

Comment: @ingsaurabh, I've read that `synchronized` only works for multiple threads rather than processes.

Answer (score 0):

The docs for `SharedPreferences` say that it currently does not support use across multiple processes.  Synchronization is a solution only if you're dealing with multiple threads, not multiple processes.  For safe access by multiple processes, you need to create a `Service` or `ContentProvider`.